# Modeling ASP.NET Core Controller update for multiple possible outcomes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio as a reference and am interested in the way updates should be handled.

Given the following code for an update method:

```
public class Todo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public bool Completed { get; set; }
}

public class UpdateTodoRequest
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public bool Completed { get; set; }
}

public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateAsync([FromRoute] id, UpdateTodoRequest todoUpdateRequest)
{
    if (todo == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    var result = await _todoService.UpdateAsync(id, todoUpdateRequest);

    // Here I can have three possible results
    //  1. Todo with that Id was not found - 404
    //  2. Todo didn't pass validation rules - 400 (together with list of rules that didn't pass)
    //  3. Everything was successful - 204
}
```

How should (can) I model `_todoService.UpdateAsync` method signature so that it could handle all of three cases I've listed?

I could refactor that as follows:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateAsync([FromRoute] id, UpdateTodoRequest todoUpdateRequest)
{
    if (todo == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    // Getting the whole Todo by id coming from route
    var todo = await _todoService.GetById(id);

    if (todo == null)
    {
        // Returning 404 here
        return NotFound();
    }

    // Updating values coming from request to todo taken from service
    todo.Title = todoUpdateRequest.Title;
    todo.Completed = todo.Completed;

    // Result = boolean for success/failure
    var result = await _todoService.UpdateAsync(todo);

    return result ? NoContent() : BadRequest();
}
```

In this version I can almost handle cases I wanted:

- I can get 404 if there's no todo with that Id
- I can return 400 for validation issues (*HOWEVER without validation criteria*)
- I can get 204 if update was successful

So how could I model my service so that controller could handle all of these three cases above? Also I'm open to any kind of suggestions to do things differently or links to SO questions where this has been discussed to death.

I've also thought that it would make sense to use a `Either` Monad from functional world: https://mikhail.io/2016/01/validation-with-either-data-type-in-csharp/ to indicate success/validation errors and return correct response type based on its' result.

Answer (score 1):

Because there are multiple return types and paths in the action, liberal use of the `[ProducesResponseType]` attribute is necessary. This attribute produces more descriptive response details for API help pages generated by tools like Swagger. `[ProducesResponseType]` indicates the known types and HTTP status codes to be returned by the action. Refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.2#iactionresult-type).

You could use below code to return three kinds of responses' type.

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateAsync([FromRoute] id, UpdateTodoRequest todoUpdateRequest)
```

Comment: I understand this, but this is controller. My question was how to model service signature (or perhaps return type) so that controller can handle these three possible cases.